# Two dimentional array printing rows

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Okay, so I need to print 10 rows from 1 to 10 and 15 columns in every row from 1 to 15 with lines in between numbers. The second subroutine runs on its own, but only prints 0's and the first subroutine is me trying to give value to rows and columns, but I know I'm doing it very wrong. Any help is appreciated

```
static int ROWS = 10;
static int COLUMNS = 15;
static int[][] myArray = new int[10][15];
static int i;      // loops through the number of rows
static int j;      // loops through the number of columns  
static int num1 = 0;
static int num2 = 0;

    public static void vlueArray() {

    for (i = 1; i < ROWS; i++) {
       myArray[i][j]= num1++;
        for (j = 1; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
          myArray[i][j] = num2++;

          System.out.print(myArray[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}



public static void display2DArray() {

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {

            System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("_____________________________________________________________");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialized elements in array and that is why you are getting zero displayed because int values are always initialized by the compiler even if you don't initialize them. The default value of int is 0.

Initialize your 2D array like this:

```
int[][] myArray = new int[10][15]{{2,3},{3,5},..........};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. First, you don't have very good syntax, while the way you have this set up does work, let me give you a couple of tips about settings this up, and then we can fix your problem fairly easily.

Some general rules here:

- You don't have to initialize loop variables in the class variables, just initialize them in the loop structure (I'll show you this below).
- Use the `ROW` and `COLUMN` in declaring your array, it helps make sure the array length values are the same throughout.
- Your loop for creating the values in `vlueArray` is incorrect. I'll show you some correct formatting for placing these values below.
- When you array is initialized, each place in the array (if it is an integer array) is automatically given a value of zero. You can change this, but since the first method doesn't run correctly, printing the values in the array without changing them will give the array of zeros.

Now, it seems like you want to just have 1 - 15 on 10 different rows. To do this, you only need one variable, so my response code will only have one variable, but if this isn't what you want, I'd be glad to help you get a different setup.

So now that you have a little bit of background information, let's get you some working code.

```
static int ROWS = 10; //Your row count.
static int COLUMNS = 15; //Your column count.
static int num = 0; //Our number.

//Using the constants to make sure rows and columns values match everywhere.
static int[][] myArray = new int[ROWS][COLUMNS];

public static void fillArray() {

//Initializing the loop variables in the loop is the common practice.
//Also, since the first index is zero, the loop needs to start at 0, not 1.
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
        //If you want 0 - 14, use `num++`.
        //If you want 1-15, use `++num`.
        myArray[i][j] = num++;
    }
    num = 0; //This sets num back to zero after cycling through a whole row.
}

//Your display method works just fine.
public static void display2DArray() {

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {

            System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("_____________________________________________________________");
}
```